# How to make wolfram simplify sqrt[x^2] when x > 0?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

when x>0, Sqrt[x^2] equals x, how to do it in wolfram?

It seems can't even simplify Sqrt[x^4]

Comment: `Assuming[x > 0, Sqrt[x^2] // Simplify]` or `Assuming[x > 0 && n \[Element] Integers, Sqrt[x^(2 n)] // Simplify]`

Comment: I've never seen `// Simplify` syntax before, what does it mean?

Comment: The // operator is called a "post-fix" notation, a notation in which the operation to be performed is placed at the end rather than at the begining. For example `x^2//Sqrt` is the same as `Sqrt[x^2]`. Post-fix operation is sometimes convenient when you add a final operation on a result, e.g., `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],1000]//Mean`.

Comment: @BobHanlon In my case the expression I want to simplify is `Simplify[Solve[D[(a21 a32 b13 r1 r2 r3 t1)/(a12 a23 b31 + a23 b31 r1 t1 + a21 b31 r1 r2 t1 + a21 a32 r1 r2 r3 t1)-t1, t1]==0,t1]]`, if I put `Assuming[r1>0&&r2>0&&r3>0,`  in front of it, it just hangs up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Options[Solve]

(* {Assumptions :> $Assumptions, Cubics -> Automatic, GeneratedParameters -> C, 
 InverseFunctions -> Automatic, MaxExtraConditions -> 0, Method -> Automatic, 
 Modulus -> 0, Quartics -> Automatic, VerifySolutions -> Automatic, 
 WorkingPrecision -> ∞} *)
```

In later versions of Mathematica, `Solve` takes the option `Assumptions`. With your problem, including the assumptions in `Solve` significantly slows `Solve`. Separate the simplification from the solve operation.

```
sol1 = Solve[
   D[(a21 a32 b13 r1 r2 r3 t1)/(a12 a23 b31 + a23 b31 r1 t1 + 
         a21 b31 r1 r2 t1 + a21 a32 r1 r2 r3 t1) - t1, t1] == 0, t1];

sol2 = Assuming[r1 > 0 && r2 > 0 && r3 > 0,
  Simplify[sol1]]

(* {{t1 -> -((a12 a23^2 b31^2 r1 + a12 a21 a23 b31^2 r1 r2 + 
        a12 a21 a23 a32 b31 r1 r2 r3 + √(a12 a21 a23 a32 b13 b31 r1^3 \
r2 r3 (a23 b31 + a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))/(r1^2 (a23 b31 + 
          a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))}, {t1 -> -((a12 a23^2 b31^2 r1 + 
        a12 a21 a23 b31^2 r1 r2 + 
        a12 a21 a23 a32 b31 r1 r2 r3 - √(a12 a21 a23 a32 b13 b31 r1^3 \
r2 r3 (a23 b31 + a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))/(r1^2 (a23 b31 + 
          a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))}} *)
```

Looking at the effect of simplification:

```
LeafCount /@ {sol1, sol2}

(* {485, 163} *)
```

**EDIT:** If you want further simplification, use `FullSimplify` instead of `Simplify`

```
sol3 = Assuming[r1 > 0 && r2 > 0 && r3 > 0, FullSimplify[sol1]]

(* {{t1 -> -((a12 a23 b31 r1 (a23 b31 + 
           a21 r2 (b31 + 
              a32 r3)) + √(a12 a21 a23 a32 b13 b31 r1^3 r2 r3 (a23 b31 +
              a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))/(r1^2 (a23 b31 + 
          a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))}, 
    {t1 -> (-a12 a23 b31 r1 (a23 b31 + a21 r2 (b31 + 
            a32 r3)) + √(a12 a21 a23 a32 b13 b31 r1^3 r2 r3 (a23 b31 + 
           a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))/(r1^2 (a23 b31 + 
        a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2)}} *)
```

**EDIT 2:** Include some manual manipulation,

```
sol4 = Assuming[r1 > 0 && r2 > 0 && r3 > 0, 
  FullSimplify[sol2 /. Sqrt[expr_] :> (r1*Sqrt[expr/r1^2])]]

(* {{t1 -> -((a12 a23 b31 (a23 b31 + a21 r2 (b31 + 
              a32 r3)) + √(a12 a21 a23 a32 b13 b31 r1 r2 r3 (a23 b31 + 
             a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))/(r1 (a23 b31 + 
          a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))}, 
    {t1 -> (-a12 a23 b31 (a23 b31 + a21 r2 (b31 + 
            a32 r3)) + √(a12 a21 a23 a32 b13 b31 r1 r2 r3 (a23 b31 + 
           a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2))/(r1 (a23 b31 + 
        a21 r2 (b31 + a32 r3))^2)}} *)
```

Comparing the results,

```
LeafCount /@ {sol1, sol2, sol3, sol4}

(* {485, 163, 141, 135} *)
```

Comment: I am new to Wolfram, so would you please explain this line `FullSimplify[sol2 /. Sqrt[expr_] :> (r1*Sqrt[expr/r1^2])]` and this one `LeafCount /@ {sol1, sol2, sol3, sol4}`?

Comment: @Diaa - In `sol2` there are terms of the form `Sqrt[coef * r1^3]` which, to aid in the simplification, I want converted to `r1 Sqrt[coef*r1]` (valid since `r1 > 0`). This is accomplished with the replacement rule `Sqrt[expr_] :> (r1*Sqrt[expr/r1^2])]`. The `LeafCount` of an expression is a measure of the expression's complexity. `LeafCount /@ {sol1, sol2, sol3, sol4}` maps `LeafCount` onto the solutions to show the reduction in complexity as the simplification progressed.

Comment: Thanks, so what are the names of the following operators to look for in the documentation of Wolfram: `/.` and `:>`?

Comment: @Diaa - Use the online documentation. In Mathematica, hover over the operator/command and look at the tooltip. Or highlight the operator/command and press `F1` for help. `/.` is `ReplaceAll` and `:>` is `RuleDelayed`